# Replaced door hinges and now the door won't close - hits the door stop on the hinge side

Tags: doors, hinges, jamb

I replaced the 3.5" hinges on an interior door with hinges of the same size. The only difference that I can see between the old and new hinges is that the barrels on the old set are slightly larger.

When I attempt to close the door now, the door hits the stop on the hinge side before it's completely closed - making it impossible to close the door.

I tried adding shims, since the hinges were not flush, but this didn't do anything to fix the problem. Any ideas of what could be happening here?

Comment: can you provide pictures of the hinges?

Comment: Sounds like the depth of the hinges changed on the door side. Are the hinges set exactly as they were in the mortices? A 1/16th" is a lot in the application... Or perhaps the hinge is lapped out of the mortice on the jamb side, that will make it hinge bound and stick at the stop...

Answer (score 1):

Resetting the hinges so the door sits a little further from the stop will work.  Sometimes it is easier to remove the door stop and reset it away from the the door a bit, especially if you are refinishing the door jamb anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree with the answer before mine in other words you set the hinges too far back towards the door stop that the door is now coming in contact with.

Comment: Thank you for all of the responses. The thing that doesn't make sense to me is that I'm using the same screw holes as the previous hinges, and the hinge is the same size. It almost sounds to me like there is a minuscule difference between the size of the old hinge and the new hinge. Otherwise, wouldn't the screws force it to be set in the same place?

Comment: That would have to be exactly right

Comment: Thank you everyone. I'm going to try re-setting the hinges slightly further up and see how it goes. I'll update once I've had a chance to do this.